# Text Parsing and Nested Collection Transposition in F#

Tags: collections, f#, nested, text-parsing, transpose

I parse data from a csv file that looks like this:

```
X,..,..,Dx,..,..
Y,..,..,Dy,..,..
X,..,..,Dx,..,..
Y,..,..,Dy,..,..
X,..,..,Dx,..,..
Y,..,..,Dy,..,..
```

Each row is an element of an array of a type I defined and used with FileHelpers.  This probably isn't relevant, but I'm including this incase someone knows a trick I could do at this stage of the process using FileHelpers.

I'm only interested in pairs X,Dx and Y,Dy
The data could have more than just X & Y eg.. (X,Dx); (Y,Dy); (Z,Dz); ...

I'll call the number of letters nL

The goal is to get the averages of Dx, Dy, ... for each group by processing an array of all D's which has SUM(nIterations) * nL elements.

I have a list of numbers of iterations:

```
let nIterations = [2000; 2000; 2000; 1000; 500; 400; 400; 400; 300; 300]
```

And for each of these numbers, I will have that many "letter groups." So the rows of data of interest for nIterations.[0], are rows 0 to (nIterations.[0] * nL)

To get the rows of interest for nIterations.[i], I make a list "nis" which is the result of a scan operation performed on nIterations.

```
let nis = List.scan (fun x e -> x + e) 0 nIterations
```

Then to isolate the nItertions.[i] group ..

```
let group = Array.sub Ds (nis.[i]*nL) (nIterations.[i]*nL)
```

Here's the whole thing:

```
nIterations |> List.mapi (fun i ni ->
    let igroup = Array.sub Ds (nis.[i]*nL) (ni*nL)
    let groupedbyLetter = (chunk nL igroup)

    let sums = seq { for idx in 0..(nL - 1) do
                         let d = seq { for g in groupedbyLetter do 
                                           yield (Seq.head (Seq.skip idx g)) }
                         yield d |> Seq.sum }

    sums |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x / (float ni))) ) |> List.ofSeq
```

That "chunk" function is one I found on SO:

```
let rec chunk n xs =
    if Seq.isEmpty xs then Seq.empty
    else
        let (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs
        Seq.append (Seq.singleton ys) (chunk n zs)
```

I have verified this works, and gets me what I want - a size nL collection of size nIterations.Length collections.

The problem is speed - this only works on small data sets; the sizes I'm working with in the example I've given are too big.  It gets "hung" at the chunk function.

So my question is: **How do I go about improving the speed of this whole process? (and/or) What is the best (or atleast a better) way to do that "transposition"**

I figure I could:

- try to rearrange the data as I'm reading it in
- try to index the elements directly
- try breaking the process into smaller stages or "passes"
- ???

Comment: Have you tried using the csv type provider? http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

Comment: Can you provide an example of concrete input that you have and a concrete output that you'd like to get? I'm getting a bit lost :-). Also, it is a bit hard to answer without a runnable source code - if you could share a version that runs somewhere, that would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

```
let averages =
    (nIterations |> List.mapi (fun i ni ->
        let igroup = Array.sub Ds (nis.[i]*nL) (ni*nL)
        let groupedbyLetter = 
            [| for a in 1..nL..igroup.Length do 
                   yield igroup.[(a - 1)..(a - 1)+(nL-1)] |]

        [| for i in 0..(nL - 1) do
               yield [| for j in 0..(groupedbyLetter.Length - 1) do
                            yield groupedbyLetter.[j].[i] |] 
               |> Array.average |]) )

let columns = [| for i in 0..(nL - 1) do
                     yield [| for j in 0..(nIterations.Length - 1) do
                                  yield averages.[j].[i] |] 
                     |]
```

The "columns" function is just transposing the data again so I can easily print..

```
               ----Average Ds----
nIterations       X    Y    Z
   2000          0.2  0.7  1.2
    ...          ...  ...  ...
    ...          ...  ...  ...
```

e.g. averages returns

```
[[x1,y1,z1,..], [x2,y2,z2,..], ... ]
```

and columns gives me

```
[ [x1,x2,..], [y1,y2,..], [z1,z2,..], ...]
```